# Why can't I find Java desktop application in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded Netbeans 7.3 with all bundle and installed it successfully on Windows 7.  But I can't find Java Desktop Application which should be under Java category when add new project as 7.0 does.  Where is it? Or what is the substitute one in 7.3? I need something to create GUI by dragging components.  Thanks.

Comment: It's under "Swing GUI Forms" Category.

Answer (score 0):

To create a desktop application with NetBeans use a `Java Application` from the category `Java` or `Maven`.

You can then add forms to this application and use them.

If you create a new form of the type `JFrame` this frame get automatically a `main()` method which is needed to start the program.

Comment: this answers only one part of the question. please allow me to add comment here regarding the other part: The "Java Desktop Application" plugin was dropped from Netbeans. Creating gui is possible as always. but if you wanted the functionality of the plugin, you need to go for coding with Netbeans Platform. or create the database code yourself.